# How do I sort a directory full of pictures into sub-directories based on the image name?

Tags: file, bash, shell

I want to take all of the files in `/media/mdrive/dump/`:

```
1COD-234355.jpg
MAK-LXT218.jpg
ZIR-CON145.jpg
```

And create and sort them into the following directories:

```
/media/mdrive/dump/1/1COD-234355.jpg
/media/mdrive/dump/M/MAK-LXT218.jpg
/media/mdrive/dump/Z/ZIR-CON145.jpg
```

How would I do that?

Answer (score 4):

This script takes a directory as the first argument and performs what you need:

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR="$1"

if [ -z "$DIR" ]; then
    echo >&2 "Syntax: $0 <directory>"
    exit 1
fi

if [ ! -d "$DIR" ]; then
    echo >&2 "\"$DIR\" is not a directory"
    exit 1
fi

cd "$DIR"

for file in *.jpg *.JPG; do
    first=${file::1}
    mkdir -p $first && mv $file $first/;
done
```

`head -c xx` will return the first `xx` characters of its input (here, the filename). `mkdir -p` will skip directory creation if it already exists.

Comment: I keep getting this error with a couple files

"mkdir: cannot create directory `1COU-4735196.JPG': File exists"

it looks like it's trying to create a directory by that file name

Comment: Hmm, JPG in uppercase? Add `*.JPG` to the pattern in `for` then. I cannot see how the error you mentioned can happen.

Comment: I'm trying to run the program from ~/ but I'm not sure how to perform that script in that directory without adding "cd /media/mdrive/dump" at the beginning and then "cd ~/" at the end

Comment: Make the script take a directory as the first argument, then, and cd into the script before running the for loop

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't actually know how to do that.  I'm pretty new at shell scripting

Comment: Thanks.  Sorry, makes sense.  I'm a knob

Comment: You can get the first character of the variable without the echo and head. first="${file::1}"

Comment: Still having a problems with this.  It seems to create one directory and then move all of the files into it regardless of the first letter.  For example, if i'm working with file 1COU-1234.jpg and MAK-1234.jpg it will created the 1\ directory and then move both files into it.  I want to create 1\ and M\

Comment: @Terry-Crunchbang this is not normal. If your filename is `MAK-1234.jpg`, `${file::1}` evaluates to `M`, not `1`.

Comment: I keep getting "sort.sh: 20: Bad substitution"

Comment: why not look for a program that is made to do this like "Drop-It" http://sourceforge.net/projects/dropit/files/DropIt/v5.3.1/DropIt_v5.3.1_Portable.zip/download

Answer (score 0):

to make two directories you could try something like

```
    dir "/media/mdrive/dump/1/" :: CD would also work here 
    mkdir folder 1
    mkdir folder 2
```

from here I think you can continue with your IF statements and so forth.
all you need to do is set the dir commands with the Direct path takes the guess work out.
then to check each just do:

```
    start explorer.exe "the folder's path here"
```

it should open the folder to view the files